# Quick help in rebuilding an automake project

Tags: c++, c, makefile, automake

I got the source code of a project (which I can't reach the author any more), that uses automake. I'm not familiar with system and all I want to do is rebuild the project.

I have the following files in the project:

```
Makefile.am
Makefile.in
Makefile
```

I've modified the Makefile.am file to fit the paths on my system, but how should I run it regenerate the Makefile.

Note: I'm not currently interested in learning automake, just recompiling this project.

Comment: For one `automake` project, I have a setup script that contains: `aclocal -I config &&
libtoolize --automake &&
autoheader &&
automake --foreign --add-missing &&
autoconf`.  You may be able to miss out some or all of those steps; `libtoolize` and `autoheader` in particular; the `aclocal -I config` looks for files in the `config` sub-directory of the top-level of the source.  Have you looked for guidance in the INSTALL or README or similar docs in the source?

Comment: I don't have them... It is an old university project, where the student who wrote is nowhere to be found...

Comment: If you don't have any of the `auto*` tools, you're stuck.  You can't regenerate `Makefile` from `Makefile.am` without at least `automake` and `autoconf`.  You'll have to manually hack the Makefile, probably, to match the changes in `Makefile.am`.

Comment: I have autotools, I don't have a README/INSTALL or any kind of information how he built the project except the files above

Answer (score 3):

to bootstrap an autoconf build-system, you might use

```
 $ autoreconf -fiv
```

which will call automake, aclocal, autoheaders as needed, and generate the `configure` script. after that ou can do the usual

```
 $ ./configure && make && make install
```

as proposed by milos_ladni

but you will definitely need `configure.ac` (or `configure.in` if it's an older project), else the project is simply missing some core parts.

if those are missing, you could go and try to modify `Makefile` directly (good luck), but it might be easier to just recreate a configure.ac from scratch (and hope that the project doesn't have too many dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

$ ./configure --prefix=some_directory

$ make

$ make install

http://inti.sourceforge.net/tutorial/libinti/autotoolsproject.html#AP05

Comment: @BenjaminK, do you have a `configure.in` or a `configure.ac`?  With those files you can make the `configure` file.